# Ubuntu 22.04 not poweroff/restart

Tags: 22.04, shutdown

Ubuntu 22.04 not poweroff.

I have two Ubuntus, 22.04 and 20.04. I tried to power off my Ubuntu 22.04, but it does not power off no matter what I do. It shows this Lenovo screen every time I power off or restart.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also experiencing the same thing.. it's usually related with discreet graphic driver that's not installed correctly.

If you had the same hardware as I had (dual graphics - amd radeon & nvidia) you can do this:

0. turn off computer with power off button (about 5 seconds)
1. turn on and enter BIOS to disable 'secure boot' in BIOS (since nvidia use proprietary driver)
2. install discreet graphic (since I had dual graphics on my laptop, onboard amd & nvidia)
3. reboot and enable back 'secure boot' in BIOS after that

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I switched my graphics device *Switchable Graphics* to *UMA Graphics*, and the issue has been resolved.

[image]